# Duda con urls en Django 2.2

Tags: django, django-urls

`[No resuelto]`

Tengo una duda de cual es la mejor manera, y la buena o mejor practica para llamar a las `urls` en `django`(no se como se llama este método, de llamar a las `urls`)....

Esta seria la primera forma:

```
# pages / urls.py

pages_patterns = ([
    path('', PageListView.as_view(), name='pages'),
    path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', PageDetailView.as_view(), name='page'),
    path('create/', PageCreate.as_view(), name = 'create')

], 'pages')
```

---

```
# proyecto / urls.py

from pages.urls import pages_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('pages/', include(pages_patterns))
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Y pues se les llama de esta forma en el *template tag* `url`:

```
{% url 'pages:subpagina' %}
```

---

Esta seria la segunda forma que prácticamente se añade solo una linea de código(`app_name`) y funciona de la misma manera que la primera forma:

```
# pages / urls.py

app_name = 'pages'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PageListView.as_view(), name='pages'),
    path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', PageDetailView.as_view(), name='page'),
    path('create/', PageCreate.as_view(), name = 'create')
]
```

---

```
# proyecto / urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pages/', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

Funciona igual que la primera forma(template tag `url`).

Bueno mi pregunta es ¿Cual es la de mejor forma de hacerlo?, y tampoco se muy bien como funciona lo de la `app_name`, también vi algo de `namespace` en los `paths` de las `urls`,  que no entendí muy bien como funcionaban... se los agradecería mucho que me explicaran como funcionan...

Answer (score 2):

Saludos te dejare un par de **Buenas Practicas de Django**

**El Estilo de Código**

Aqui no hay mucho que comentar, mas que Django esta escrito en **Python** por lo tanto su codigo debe ser escrito respetando la guia **PEP8** la cual la puedes encontrar [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#python-style).

**Settings**(settings.py)

settings.py es uno de los módulos principales en tu app, en el se definen los parámetros con los que ha de funcionar tu aplicación, es importante mantener limpio este módulo.

Podemos hacer nuestro **settings.py** muy modular, e importar lo que se necesita en el momento. Por ejemplo, las configuraciones de **logging** , o las configuraciones correspondientes al ambiente de desarrollo que son típicamente diferentes a las de producción.

**urls**

En nuestro proyecto veremos un archivo **urls.py** que no es mas que un módulo que contiene la información de cada una e las URLs dentro de nuestro proyecto. Me ha tocado ver **urls.py** tan largos como un testamento, y no es nada bonito tener un módulo así de grande, sobre todo porque es confuso.

Que podemos hacer?. Bueno, en principio, tener un urls.py en cada **app** de tu proyecto, de esta forma cada app será independiente, se reducirá el tamaño del archivo principal y te será mas fácil ubicar las urls en caso de agregar/editar/borrar. La otra, en el caso de que nuestra app tenga muchas urls, es **modularizar**, puedes repartir las urls en mas módulos dependiendo de cada sección dentro de tu app.

Ejemplo:

urls.py(principal)

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'empresa/', include('empresa.urls', namespace='empresa')),
    ...
    ...

]
```

Si te fijas tenemos alli definido o incluido un archivo de mis apps(urls.py) uno por cada app, lo que se hace es dentro de cada app crear un archivo llamado urls.py este puede se lo define algo asi:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from empresa.views import ListadoEmpresa, CrearEmpresa, EditarEmpresa

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^administrar_empresa', ListadoEmpresa.as_view(), name='administrar_empresa'),
    url(r'^crear_empresa', CrearEmpresa.as_view(), name='crear_empresa'),
    url(r'^editar_empresa/(?P<pk>\d+)', EditarEmpresa.as_view(), name='editar_empresa'),
]
```

En este caso es el archivo **urls.py** de una app llamada **empresa** se debe definir las urls importando como normalmente se hace con views.py.

**Plantillas(templates)**

Las plantillas en Django están en básicamente en dos lugares, en el directorio base de tu proyecto y en el de cada app, ahí deberá haber un directorio llamado templates. Lo importante aquí es que las plantillas de tu app deben estar en el directorio templates dentro de tu app. Las plantillas “base” o genéricas podrían estar en tu directorio templates en el directorio base.

Ejemplo de estructura:

```
BASE_DIR/
        /myproject/
                  /settings.py
                  /urls.py
        /templates/
                  /base.html
                  /header.html
                  /footer.html
        /my_app/
               /models.py
               /views.py
               /urls.py
               /admin.py
```

**Contenido estatico(static)**

Lo mismo que con las plantillas. Cada app debe mantener su contenido estático para cada una de ellas, con esto mantienes la independencia de la app y permites que pueda ser usada en otros proyectos.

El contenido estático pueden ser:

- imágenes
- JavaScript
- CSS

**Nota.-**

no se debe confundir el contenido estático con el contenido que sube el usuario final, este contenido que sube el usuario va al directorio “**Media**”

Espero te sirva y suerte...para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar la guia oficial de Django hallaras mas detalles de todo eso...!!

Comment: Y como funciona `namespace` y `app_name`?